# shell says "command not found" error for data echoed to a telnet command

Tags: bash, awk, exec, telnet

```
find /data/backup/ -name 20140202* -exec awk -F"|" '$23!=0 {print"|"$14"|"$23}' {}       
\; > Day1.txt

host='XX.XX.XX.XX'
user='root'
passwd='root'
(
echo "$user"
echo "$passwd"
echo "cd /data/"
echo "find /data/backup/ -name rec20140202* -exec awk -F"|" '$23!=0 {print"|"$14"|"$23}'  
{} \; > remoteDay1.txt"
echo "exit" )| telnet "$host"
```

In the above code fragment first find command is working fine but second find command (inside telnet part) is resulting in the following error:

---

```
testnew.sh: line 27: '3!=0 {print: command not found
testnew.sh: line 27: 4: command not found
testnew.sh: line 27: 3: command not found
testnew.sh: line 27: }' {} \; > remoteDay1.txt: command not found
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

---

Pls help

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
echo "find /data/backup/ -name rec20140202* -exec awk -F"|" '$23!=0 {print"|"$14"|"$23}'
```

You double quote the echo argument and also use double quotes in -F"|" and even in the awk script.
The shell then attempts to construct a 4-program pipe equivalent to

```
 echo "find /data/backup/ -name rec20140202* -exec awk -F" |
 " '$23!=0 {print"                                         |
 "$14"                                                     |
 "$23}' {} \; > remoteDay1.txt"
```

Since the shell's *positional parameters* `$1` and `$2` are empty, you get exactly the errors you described.
If you want double quotes in double quotes, you need to escape them:

```
echo \"foo\"
```

echos `"foo"` including the quotes.
Note that there is no way to quote single quotes withing a single quoted string. You also want to hide the `$23` etc from shell expansion. Escape them as `\$`. I suggest using

```
echo "find ... -F\"|\" '\$23!=0 {print \"|\"\$14\"|\"\$23}' {} \;>remoteDay1.txt"
```